# Is "No soy de aquí" idiomatic for "I am a stranger here too"?

Tags: traducción

When people ask me the way while I am in Spanish speaking countries I usually reply

> No soy de aquí
>
> Lo siento, pero no soy de aquí

At home I would have said "Sorry I  am a stranger here too" or "Sorry I am not from around here". My reply had the desired effect, they went and asked someone else but is it the idiomatic way to say it?

Comment: It is perfect. To mimic the _too_ in your English version, you can add a _también_ and say _Tampoco soy de aquí_.

Comment: It is right. You can also read it as _I don't belong here_: The preposition _de_ expressing belonging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it as you mentioned it.

1. *Sorry, I'm not from around here*.
   This is a very formal way to say it. In Spanish this is

   > *Lo siento, no soy de estos alrededores*,

   but this would imply that you are from another city. (But in the same country.)
   This is rarely used. Nowadays I doubt anyone would say it like this, so it's better not to use it.

   In the case of *sorry, I'm a stranger here too*, it's not bad but this something I wouldn't use.
2. *No soy de aquí*.
   This is perfectly idiomatic. It's more like saying implicitly *I'm from another country.*

However, you'd give yourself away because of the accent. We can automatically tell your accent before you say you're not from here.

Comment: _no soy de estos alrededores_ a mí me suena incluso mal. Con lo fácil que es decir _no soy de aquí_.

Comment: @fedorqui Ese es el problema con las diferencias regionales. Acá en Chile suena bien sin ningún problemas, pero casi nadie lo usa.

Comment: @Ustanak no estoy de acuerdo contigo, yo también soy de Chile y nunca lo he escuchado de esa manera. A mí también me suena mal.

Comment: @VladimirNu Bueno, depende del lugar que seamos. Al menos yo lo escuché varias veces.

Comment: @Ustanak Al menos en Santiago no se dice de esa manera, y tampoco creo que se correcto decirlo. Pero sí, puede que en otros lugares del país lo digan así. Al menos yo nunca lo había escuchado. Si alguien lo dijera así, probablemente lo corregiría. Yo diría mejor `no soy de por aquí` para referirme a `I'm not from around here`.

Comment: @VladimirNu Bueno me refiero hace harto tiempo atrás porque igual eso ya no lo escucho en años, pero quería hacer la mención de todas formas.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and yet more discussion of regional variations.

Comment: "Give yourself away because of the accent" is not an idiomatic English expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say `I'm a stranger here too`, when referring to someone that is most likely to be a foreigner, same as you are in that place:

> También soy extranjero.

Or if you are a foreigner and asked from apparently a local, or when you don't know or you are not sure, just say:

> Soy extranjero.

Or if you are both strangers in a place but not necessary foreigner, you can say:

> Tampoco soy de aquí.

But in most cases I would say just the way you mentioned:

> No soy de aquí.
>
> Lo siento, pero no soy de aquí.